# Can't drop a table because of "dependent objects exist"

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, ucanaccess

My problem is very simple. When I try to drop a table by doing `DROP TABLE SCCM;` using UCanAccess, I get these error messages :

```java
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: dependent objects exist: PUBLIC."DOUBLONS SCCM POSTE" in statement [DROP TABLE SCCM ]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: dependent objects exist: PUBLIC."DOUBLONS SCCM POSTE" in statement [DROP TABLE SCCM ]
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: dependent objects exist: PUBLIC."DOUBLONS SCCM POSTE"
```

I understand that this happens because "something" need "something else" so the table cannot be dropped however, I have no idea what are those "things".

Also something else, when I try to execute the drop command directly into Access, I don't have that dependant objet error.

Is there a way to force drop a table or something like that ?

Edit : added code snippets

This is how I execute my DROP query

```java
Connection connection = Access.getConnection();
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
System.out.println("DROP TABLE " + this.name + " ;");
statement.execute("DROP TABLE " + this.name + " ;");
```

And this is how I get my connection

```java
public class Access {
    private final String urlTemplate = "jdbc:ucanaccess://redacted/req.accdb";
    private static Connection connection;

    private Access() throws SQLException {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(urlTemplate);
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        if (connection == null) {
            new Access();
        }

        return connection;
    }
}
```

(Also; I know it would have been better to use `PreparedStatement` but in my case, it is not possible)

Comment: Could be a relation to another table?

Comment: No, I don't have any. I've just inserted the values without any relations / index / anything. (I have imported the values from an Excel file)

Comment: Post your procedure code - edit question. Is it like this example https://github.com/andrew-nguyen/ucanaccess/blob/master/src/test/java/net/ucanaccess/test/DropTableTest.java

Comment: @June7 I updated my question with my code and yes I try to drop my table like in this example, I have also tried with `.executeUpdate` to be sure and it also doesn't work.

Comment: The exception message tells you exactly what the dependent object is. `DROP TABLE SCCM` is failing because `"DOUBLONS SCCM POSTE"` exists.